# Написание повторяющихся слов с частицей "не" между ними

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правило, регламентирующее пунктуацию в сочетаниях наподобие *"Думай(?) не думай, а делать надо"*; *"Зелёный(?) не зелёный, но с прозеленью"*; *"Столб(?) не столб, но какая-никакая подпорка"*.

Кажется, я встречал правило или пример у Розенталя, но сейчас никак не могу найти.

В Нацкорпусе большинство примеров — без знака, но интересует, есть ли именно фиксация в каком-либо справочнике.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> В Нацкорпусе большинство примеров — без знака, но интересует, есть ли
> именно фиксация в каком-либо справочнике.

Из Розенталя:

**§ 16. Запятая при повторяющихся словах**

<…>

**4. Запятая не ставится:**

1. между двумя повторяющимися словами, из которых второе употреблено с отрицанием ***не,*** если сочетание этих слов образует смысловое целое, выражающее неполное отрицание или неопределенность в обозначении чего-либо: ***Страшно не страшно**, а на душе как-то строго (Леск.); **Дождь не дождь**, а паши (Ш.); На нём надето что-то круглое: **сюртук не сюртук, пальто не пальто, фрак не фрак**, а что-то среднее (С.‑Щ.); **Рад не рад**, корми его (П.); Попал в стаю, **лай не лай**, а хвостом виляй (Ч.); **Маленький не маленький**, а это знать не мешает; **Была не была** — пойду*…

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=105#pp105